# How do I learn to write efficient and maintainable C code?

Tags: c

My current experience with programming is limited to hacking together some shell scripts and some assembly in the past. However, I learned the basic syntax of C code in college.

I want to learn how to write efficient C code, I an confused whether to start with K&R or C Programming: A Modern Approach. Also should I study some algorithm books alongside so that I don't end up writing inefficient code right from the beginning?

Comment: consider the platform too: what is efficent in some platform is not on another...

Comment: @Felice: The topics an *algorithm* book covers is the kind of thing that makes code more scalable on *every* implementation. Not the kind of thing that gives +/- 10 ns depending on the hardware or compiler.

Comment: @delnan, you are correct but generallyt speaking algorithm books does not necessarly talk about one single language.

Comment: @Felice: Yes, because they're not bound to any language or implementation of a language - a good algorithm is always more efficient (and often just as readable) than a bad one; that's what makes knowledge of them so valuable.

Comment: @delnan but the basic question was writing *efficent* C code, and depending on the environment practices that are good in one place aren't in another: this is not necessarily bound to algorithms, but on implementation techniques that can vary among the environments

Comment: @Felice: As already mentioned, knowdlege of algorithms >>>>> any microoptimization, especially those bound to a particular platform. Not only from a "how useful in general?" point of view, but also from a "how much faster?" point of view - microoptimization can shave off a bit of overhead, perhaps speed up by a constant factor, but they will never make a bad algorithm faster than a good one for a significant amount of work. You can't write efficient C without knowing your algorithms (and data structures) and using them appropriately.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Don't worry too much about *efficient* code at this stage. Concern yourself more with clear and readable code.

As a rule, keep functions small, performing one task. If it takes too many sentences to describe what one function does, it probably needs breaking down into smaller functions.

Use descriptive variable names, rather than just x and n etc.

Start by writing programs you will enjoy developing, rather than "boring exercises that the book tells you to do." However, do follow the book's advice and guidelines.

Everybody has their own style, don't worry if your style doesn't quite match the next person's.

Above all, enjoy it! If you find learning one thing a bit boring, move on to something else, there's always loads to learn.

EDIT: Additionally, don't try to run before you can walk - I'm specifically thinking a) pointers and b) dynamic memory allocation. There's no need to use either of them at this early stage until you're comfortable.

Comment: Also consider that clearly written, straightforward code may also be *faster* code.  There was a recent thread where someone said his professor claimed that using array subscripting for multidimensional arrays (`arr[i][j]`) was slower than using pointer arithmetic (`*(*(a+i)+j)`).  Turns out that on at least one platform (gcc/linux/x86), that's not true; the second form is up to 20% slower.  Compilers are fairly smart, and know how to generate efficient code for common operations.

Comment: "As a rule, keep functions small, performing one task. If it takes too many sentences to describe what one function does, it probably needs breaking down into smaller functions." This is not exactly correct... You can write long functions up front (as long as they aren't messy) and break functionality up later. Don't implement Microsoft Windows in order to make a pong game; add more code as you need it.

Answer (score 7):

First get wet with the basics. Learn the gotchas, learn a good C style. You can't learn how to write efficient C code in one run, so it's okay to make mistakes in the beginning.

I found the best way to learn how to write efficient code is to learn how to avoid memory leaks. 
Maintainable C code requires good documentation and comments in the source. Also, it requires writing code that resists change.

Examples:

bad example:

```
int* ptr = malloc(5 * 4); //4 here being size of int.
... do something with ptr here... //<-- this is wrong!
```

Why bad? int may not always be 4. Also, in the second line you're doing something with ptr (probably assignment) without checking if it was NULL.

better example:

```
int* ptr = malloc(5*sizeof(int)); // better, always allocate with respect to int size
if (ptr) ..do something..
```

Why better? First you allocated with respect to the size of int, so even if in another architecture int's size differed, you are good.
You also check if ptr is NULL before using

Best example:

```
int* ptr = malloc(5* sizeof(*ptr));
if (ptr) .. do something.
free(ptr); // done with ptr
```

Why is this the best way? First you linked the size of allocation not with int's size, but directly with ptr's type. Now if someone for any reason changed int to long in ptr's declaration (especially if it was declared somewhere else) without changing to long inside malloc's argument; your allocation will still be correct because it directly allocates according to whatever type ptr is of.

We also free'd ptr after being done with it, to prevent a memory leak.

Comment: Casting `malloc`'s return value is C++, not C ;)

Comment: Yes, you are right. Except if it was a function pointer, of course.

Comment: I think you mean `sizeof(*ptr)` inside the malloc ... or without the parenthesis ... `sizeof *ptr`, just like there's no parenthesis in `return(NULL);` :)

Comment: You are right about the * position being before ptr in (*ptr), however I think with the parenthesis would be a lot easier to read and understand since the OP is new in C and the parenthesis are more common.

Comment: Wait! The last example is legal C?

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost, care for **portable** programming. There is a C Standard (ISO 9899:1999 aka C99 and :2011 aka C11--you need to invest ~20 bucks) and a "Unix" Standard, called [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) (freely accessible). Read them, live them. Stay away from any and all Windows and graphics programming until you're no longer a grasshopper.

As the wise man says: *The novice programs his machine. The expert programs a set of machines. The guru programs for no particular machine.*

That's the essence of portability and it will save you from a lot of questions of the form **It compiled/ran under FOO-OS with the Frobozz magic compiler, but doesn't under BAR-OS, WTF?**

Answer (score 1):

You should try reading "Writing solid code" from Steve Maguire, it's an old book, but it can teach you what you need.

Answer (score 1):

To add on to what others have said, I would recommend just writing a lot of code. Often I find that people in this field wait too long to actually code, and spend too much time reading.

Answer (score -1):

You can emulate object oriented programming.

Define entities by defining files containing structures, and functions operating on these structures. Mark functions that do not need to be seen outside as static. This will keep them hidden, so you pollute less the namespace. Create a new structure with a `new` function that returns a pointer to the newly `malloc()`ated structure, and a delete that performs the `free()`. Define simple members that operate on the structure data, accepting a pointer to the structure always as a first argument.

I suggest you to learn some OOP with python, and apply the same concepts.

Comment: OP didn't ask how to learn OOP with C (in which case the correct answer would be "don't", btw). OP asked how to learn (good) C - and emulating OOP is neither wise nor idiomatic C. (Also, you totally glossed over the main component of OOP - dynamic dispatch, which must be emulated by function pointers in the structs).

Comment: @delnan : OP ask how to write maintainable code in C, and from my personal and direct experience, coding OOP-like is a way to produce maintainable code in C.

Comment: @Stefano: Even assuming it *is* a valid solution in most cases (I doubt it has any advantages for most system programming, and that's where you should use C - it may be useful for applications, but who in their right mind writes applications in C?), it adds a whole lot of cruft and bends the language. Learning C (that doesn't, for instance, leak memory or invoke UB) can be hard enough, no need to add the trouble of building a whole OOP system nearly from scratch.

Comment: @delnan : GLib and GTK are made that way. Also, I don't think the OP is interested in system programming. More in how to do good coding with a new language, and then focus on efficiency.

Comment: @Stefano: If you imply that OOP == good code (otherwise, I don't see how the your answer fits the question): No, it isn't. It certainly is a good approach to some problems (although many of those are better solved in languages other than C). But it certainly isn't how one should start learning C. You don't start teaching C++ by template metaprogramming, do you?

Comment: @delnan : the OP didn't ask how to learn C. He asked how to write efficient and maintainable code. The learning of the language is not under discussion, and is assumed to be known. Many answered focused on the "efficiency" point. I focused on the "maintainance" point, and while doing pure OOP in C is not what I answered, I point out at OOP as a methodology to deploy code in a maintainable (i.e. organized around some criteria) way.

Answer (score -2):

To be honest in my opinion you start learning c++ which is an advance version of c language having better and efficient code here is a link that would given you a start..
Link http://internetseekho.com/learn-the-write-way-to-code-in-c-part-4-getting-data-from-user-and-displaying-it-on-screen/

Comment: This doesn't respond to the question at all